# WCF with multiple services and

Tags: rest, wcf, service

I'm trying to create a WCF that serves multiple rest services in one assembly. To test it, I have created 2 services with the same content that serves two interfaces.

I'm able to get metadata using the url

> localhost/testwebservice/services/Service1.svc?wsdl or
>   localhost/testwebservice/services/Service2.svc?wsdl

, but when I try to execute a method

> localhost/testwebservice/services/Service1.svc/GetData/0

, I get a DestinationUnreachable error.

The web.config file is

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="test.Services.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" 
          contract="test.Contracts.IService1" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="test.Contracts.IService1" />
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="test.Services.Service2">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding"
          contract="test.Contracts.IService2" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="test.Contracts.IService2" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>     
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Each .cs interface file is like this

```
namespace test.Contracts
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "GetData/{value}")]
        string GetData(string value);
    }
}
```

Each .svc file is like this

```
namespace test.Services
{
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string GetData(string value)
        {
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
        }
    }
}
```

I also, would like to access the webservice as **localhost/testwebservice/services/Service1 and localhost/testwebservice/services/service2**, instead of using .svc, but I can not config the webservice in order to remove the .svc suffix. I have tried to use the address of the endpoint, but i'm not able to make it run.

Comment: You have not specified any endpoint address and base address.

Comment: Thank you Tom, I have tríed to assign the endpoint address to Service1 and Service 2, but i get the same result, what is base address? Also, I would like to know if it is possible to change in any way how the service is called from the client and use an alias instead of the .svc file name.